# MsgBoxPrintf(win32 api) in pure C from Charles Petzold gives Chinese Output...What have i done wrong?

Tags: c, winapi, unicode

VS2013 Community edidtion OS:Win7 sp1

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>


    //VS2013 Community edidtion OS:Win7 sp1 

    //Using wchar_t for unicode and L"  " for strings

    //The MessageBoxPrintf from the book modified to take wide chars

    int CDECL MsgBoxPrintf(wchar_t *szCaption,const wchar_t *szFormat, ...)
    {
        wchar_t szBuffer[1024];
        va_list pArgsList;
        va_start(pArgsList, szFormat);

     //Using _vsnwprintf_s since _vsntprintf is deprecated   
        _vsnwprintf_s(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer)/sizeof(wchar_t), 1024-1, szBuffer, pArgsList);
        va_end(pArgsList);
    //Using MessageBoxW instead of MessageBox
        return MessageBoxW(0, szBuffer, szCaption, 0);
    }

    int
    WINAPI
    WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
            HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
            PSTR szCmdLine,
            int iCmdShow)
    {
        int cxScreen, cyScreen;
        cxScreen = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
        cyScreen = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
        MsgBoxPrintf(L"ScreenSize",L"The Screen is %i Pixels Width and %i Pixels Height.***Resolution(%ix%i)***",
            cxScreen, cyScreen, cxScreen, cyScreen
        );


        return(0);

    }
```

Everything works fine except the character ouput which is all the same chinese? symbol.No matter which kind of printf i use i cant get a correct result.
What have i done wrong?

Comment: You don't seem to be checking the return value of `_vsnwprintf_s`. If it fails, you are passing an uninitialized buffer array to your call of `MessageBoxW`. You should always initialize variables (`wchar_t szBuffer[1024]={0};`. It's probably also a good idea to specify `MB_OK` in your call to `MessageBoxW`, to improve readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your next-to-last argument for `_vsnwprintf_s`is wrong.

```
_vsnwprintf_s(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer)/sizeof(wchar_t), 1024-1, szBuffer, pArgsList);
//                                                       this ======^
```

should be **`szFormat`**; not `szBuffer`